# Can't remove hamburguer icon from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

im trying to remove the hamburguer icon because I already have one in my custom Toolbar, for remove it I have this on the activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_dieta, R.id.navigation_calendario, R.id.navigation_alimentos, R.id.navigation_perfil)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


    drawerIcon = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main_menu_icon);
    drawerIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

The icon is hidden at startup, but when I select a menu item it reappears.

[image: Startup]
[image: After click on Nav]

Comment: You are using `Toolbar` and `NavigationView` both at same time. you should only use one

Answer (score 0):

After more than 10 hours I found the answer, just delete this:

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
```